# How can I connect a Two Ubuntu 14.04 Server' Mysql Database to SAS (Serial-attached SCSI)?

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, ubuntu-14.04

We have two Ubuntu 14.04 server having Mysql DataBase connected with a SAS . How to configure both the server have same database that must store in SAS

Comment: You cannot (should not) have two mysql management systems sharing the same database storage. That would lead to chaos and frankly: why should one want to do that?

Comment: There is two web application . Each one is stored in each server . But they using same database . Thats the reason

Comment: Ah, OK, that does make sense, sure. However you cannot, as you asked, have two MySQL database management systems access the same physical storage. And actually, it is not required at all, you think too complex! You need only a single MySQL instance hosting one or more databases. Many applications can access the same MySQL instance and use the same or different databases. That actually is the idea and the power behind such database servers. So you run MySQL on one of the systems and access it from all applications via network. The physical file system is _not_ shared between systems, no need.